# Lightweight messaging on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, apache-camel, spring-integration, eai

Does you have any experience with messaging on GAE? Is there a messaging framework that can successfully run on GAE? I know that Apache Camel provides some kind of components that can run on GAE but is it really usable? What about Spring Integration? Or any other tips?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some stuff (task queues) [built into GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push) for messaging. Start with that.

The problem with running stand alone integration soltuions (Camel, Spring Integration, ActiveMQ..) on GAE is that they need to open tcp listeners and start threads, which is not really an option in GAE. At least not the standard java way.

You can run Camel to some point if you want to leverage the Camel DSL and such things. But all of Camel will not work. Camel does not include a messaging solution either.

The other option is likely to use some external messaging source, such as a RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ hosted somewhere else. Like EC2 or some [cloud service](http://www.cloudamqp.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of GAE limitations with regard to messaging solutions (threads, ...) and that is why I trying to find something that could work for us. By the way what do you mean by "Camel does not include a messaging solution either"?

Comment: By messaging, I think of something like message queueing/ pub-sub (ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, Apache Qpid, IBM WebSphere MQ and simliar). Camel is a (great) framework that you use to implement integration logic and connect to various protocols. Not a message broker.

Comment: I understand. I do not think we need a message broker, just "simple" integration with third party systems (usually via HTTP or dedicated client library wrapping HTTP) is sufficient.